# Exception occurs when running jetty with maven

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I'm trying to deploy and run my app to jetty with maven. Following is my configuration in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>9.3.0.M2</version>
      <configuration>
         <war>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</war>
       </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

But when I run `mvn jetty:run-war`, I have following exception in my console:

```
    2015-03-18 14:04:46.708:WARN:oejs.BaseHolder:main:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cocoon.servlet.multipart.MultipartFilter
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:450)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:93)
2015-03-18 14:04:46.718:WARN:oejs.BaseHolder:main:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cocoon.servlet.DebugFilter
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:450)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:95)
```

Anyone knows what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `cocoon-core-<Version>.jar` jar to your classpath. This jar contains class `org.apache.cocoon.servlet.DebugFilter` wich is missing in your classpath.

Add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cocoon</groupId>
    <artifactId>cocoon-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom file

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I followed the instruction here(http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html). What you said is not mentioned. I have another question: where's the path of the deployed web app?

Comment: @sky `$JETTY_HOME/webapps` i think.

Comment: I didn't install Jetty yet. I'm just using the plugin in maven.